# Why is Anaconda Navigator not opening?

Tags: python, powershell, jupyter-notebook, anaconda, conda

I have trouble with my anaconda3 navigator. I am using it with Python 3 and jupyter notebook. Today, because I had trouble with installing some packages, I updated everything and it worked fine. A few hours later, my anaconda navigator is not opening and when I open the PowerShell prompt I get the following error:
[image] and here:

```
failed to create process.
Invoke-Expression : Das Argument kann nicht an den Parameter "Command" gebunden werden, da es sich um eine leere
Zeichenfolge handelt.
In C:\Users\elihe\Anaconda3\shell\condabin\Conda.psm1:101 Zeichen:36
+         Invoke-Expression -Command $activateCommand;
+                                    ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidData: (:) [Invoke-Expression], ParameterBindingValidationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ParameterArgumentValidationErrorEmptyStringNotAllowed,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.Invo
   keExpressionCommand

PS C:\Users\elihe>
```

Can someone tell me what to do? I really need help :((

Comment: Please share information as text, not through images, whenever possible.

Comment: i am sorry i will edit immediately :)

Comment: Does the variable`$actiateCommand` have content? The error message indicates it is empty.

Comment: i don't know, i just uninstalled and installed the whole anaconda from the beginning and now everything works fine!

Comment: What led to that error? Can you share the contents of the environment?

Comment: I don't know...i am not a programmer...i don't know how to share the contents of the environment or even what this is..?

Answer (score 0):

I got the solution, okay it is not really a solution,but better than nothing :)
You just have to uninstall Anaconda completely from your computer, also every folder with Anaconda things. Then you have to install it completely new, as if you never had Anaconda on your computer. For me, that helped - everything goes like before this problem!

Answer (score 0):

If you just install Anaconda and when you try to lunch the Anaconda navigator and it gives you this message [There is instance of Anaconda Navigator already running](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oQbP3.png). This means you have a previous version was
not fully uninstalled or removed. So you have to find the location of the file which still excites from the previous version [Search For the previous's version file location](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F0dpB.png), then after that open the the file location.
then open the command prompt Win+R and write the command [resmon.exe] this window will appear [resmon.exe](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5t3Gk.png), in the [Associated Handles] search field write the folder name and when it appears choose the folder and then right click and [end process] to be able to delete it, then reinstall Anaconda Again.