# Anaconda navigator doesn't open, freezes at "Loading environments"

Tags: python, anaconda

After following the installation steps after downloading the "Anaconda3-2023.03-1-Windows-x86_64.exe", I tried to open the anaconda navigator and some black screens flash and fade before the green logo appears, but it eventually freezes at the "Loading environments..." step. If I try to open it again, another sequence of black screens appear, and a window pops up with the message "There is an instance of Anaconda Navigator already running.".

I tried to uninstall the app through the file "Uninstall-Anaconda3" and by deleting the folder anaconda3. Then I installed it again but the problem persisted. I opted for trying solutions in other threads like typing in the anaconda prompt `anaconda-navigator` as shown [here](https://docs.anaconda.com/free/navigator/troubleshooting/), `conda-update-conda`, etc. But it returns me with the message `'anaconda' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file`, and the same for any other command starting with "conda". It just doesn't recognize any argument I write. I also followed the steps shown [in Alex G reply](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46335789/anaconda-navigator-wont-launch-windows-10), but when typing `conda update --all`, it returned me with `EnvironmentLocationNotFound: Not a conda environment: C:\Users\Adri├á\anaconda3`.

Regarding the window with the message  "There is an instance of Anaconda Navigator already running", I tried [the steps showed in awad's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61688021/why-is-anaconda-navigator-not-opening) and opened Task Manager as well, but there was no session an already oppened in the anaconda app. Moreover, when opening the "Anaconda Powershell Prompt it appears me with the red heading as shown in the [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5QobU.png) I attach along with this message.

Thank you in advanced.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe the issue lies in your user account name Adriá, which contains diacritics. If you look at red heading message in Anaconda Powershell Prompt screenshot, you see that Anaconda doesn’t read the path (which contains your user account name with diacritics) correctly. Particularly, it can’t load Conda.psm1, but if you check the folder, you see that the file is actually there.

I tried to create two local administrator accounts on Windows 10, one with diacritics in user name and one without diacritics in user name. Surprisingly, when I tried to run Anaconda within the account with diacritics, I got the same issues and errors as you, but when I tried to do the same within the account without diacritics, it ran smoothly without any problems.