# Anaconda Navigator won't launch at all - It did launch at last

Tags: anaconda, anaconda3

Please, help!
I've installed the latest version of Anaconda, I'm in a Windows 10 version, and when I open Anaconda Navigator it does run but it stops saying it is loading environments...

My screen looks like this
[command-prompt](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EAhMU.png)

I tried several ideas from another question "Anaconda Navigator won't launch (windows 10)", at [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46335789/anaconda-navigator-wont-launch-windows-10?newreg=9e09db3572194bb5a16477cb8af5d2e2).
None of them worked. But finally I found an answer. I was running Anaconda in a folder which contained diacritics. This answer [on another post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76644341/anaconda-navigator-doesnt-open-freezes-at-loading-environments) saved me, if installed in a folder that doesn't contain diacritics Anaconda finally ran without flaw.